# Hide icons from ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView in my app. It loads each row with a XML named `file_row.xml` where I have:

- ImageView: an icon (left)
- TextView: a title (center)
- ImageView: a details icon (right)
- ImageView: a share icon (right)
- ImageView: a delete icon (right)

I want press an actionBar button and all the icons on the right will be invisible.
I have got this result for the first row, but I can not for the rest.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.file_explorer, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //ID icons
    aDel = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.aDelete);
    aShare = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.aShare);
    aView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.aDetails);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_delete:
            aDel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            aShare.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            aView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);            
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The problem is that all 'delete icons' from my ListView (one for row) have the same name (R.id.aDelete) because all are loaded from the same XML file `file_row.xml` with the `setAdapter()` method. I do not understand if all icons have the same name because they are not invisible when I put `aDel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` and the first icon only make this.

Comment: are u using any custom adapter class?

Comment: To manage items in listview you need working in adapter class.

Comment: Do you want them to stay invisible when the user scrolls the list? Anyhow you need to do all in your adapter as smail already stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to click a button and switch displaying the listview items without icons?

You approach probably fails because you are asking the activity to find the icon with `findViewById()` and it will return the first icon with that id. But there is an icon with that id for every list item.

Switching to a for loop and finding them all will not work as expected either because the listview creates the list item views dynamically. Whenever an item comes into view on the screen a list item view is created (or recycled).

You will have to make your own custom listadapter that creates list item views with a visible or invisible icon depending on your current setting. Below is an example extended from `ArrayAdapter<String>`. I don't know what kind of adapter you're using, but you can inherit from that and override the `getView()` method to set the icon visibility according to some setting that you toggle with your menu item handler.

It should look something like this in your activity class:

**Update**
Moved showIcons from activity to adapter.

```
private ListView listView;
private MyAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    adapter = new MyAdapter(this, getYourData());

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourListView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_delete:
            adapter.hideIcons();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private boolean showIcons = true;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.yourItemView, objects);
    }

    public void hideIcons() {
        // toggle setting to not show icons
        showIcons = false;
        // trigger recreating the list items, this time with inivisble icons
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // get the view through the normal ArrayAdapter mechanism
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // set the icon visibility according to your the setting
        ImageView aDel = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.aDelete);
        aDel.setVisibility(showIcons ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
        // do the other images as well
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an error in ´showIcons´ in the last row, because I have the adapter in other different class (´FileExplorerAdapter extends BaseAdapter´) than ListView (´FileExplorer´) and I have declared ´showIcons´in this last class.

Comment: Solved!! I have declared 'showIcons' variable as an **static boolean** and I have read since the adapter class as 'FileExplorer.showIcons'.

Comment: Good to hear. I made MyAdapter an inner class of the activity and that is why it had access to the activity's showIcons field. Now that I think about it again, a better approach would be to make showIcons a field of MyAdapter with a hideIcons() method to toggle it (and call notifyDataSetChanged()). You can then simply do adapter.hideIcons() from your activity's menu_delete handler. I'll update my example.

Comment: Good to hear too!! XD

Answer (score 2):

Try this. you have to go through all the views inside the `listview` and then set the disired view.

eg:

```
for( i=0;i<listView.getChildCount();i++){
   listView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.aDelete).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Using View.INVISIBLE or View.GONE is as per ur wish

Comment: This is a wrong approach and will give a NullPointerExeption for all non visible items.

Comment: I do not know if this is a wrong approach but I know that this is correct, it does not give a NullPointerException, **it works** and it is easier form to resolve my problem. Althought, I think that the winner answer is more efficient and elegant.

Answer (score -1):

If u r using any custom adapter, set your criterias there. If you are still confused, post complete code of your adapter class so that i can try to guide better